# ¿Cómo puedo crear mi propia librería de interfaz gráfica sin necesidad de usar otras librerías de interfaz gráfica?

Tags: c++, interfaz-gráfica

Sé que esta pregunta tendrá un voto negativo, pero es que tengo es que he querido saber como se puede crear mi propia librería de interfaz gráfica.

Comment: Saludos. Crear algo propio es hacer todo desde cero, invertir tu tiempo así como tu conocimiento para crear cada cosa poniéndole tu toque personal. Requiere te organices para documentar todo a fin de tener lo necesario para lo que será tu producto/librería... lo anterior entre otras cosas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pues lo primero que tienes que hacer es estudiarte la API del sistema operativo (Windows) o la librería de escritorio (KDE, Gnome, ...) si estás en Linux.

Esto es imprescindible ya que tu librería no obrará magia, sino que tendrá que comunicarse con otras librerías más básicas para proveer la interfaz gráfica.

Dicho de otra forma: El Sistema Operativo será el que te avise ante los eventos que se produzcan (clicks del ratón, pulsación de teclas, ...) así como el que te provee los recursos que necesitas (el acceso al dispositivo de la pantalla).

Así, en Windows, que en temas de programación es más bien monolítico, te encontraás con la WinAPI, que te va a dar soporte para las operaciones más básicas:

- Crear una región en la pantalla que tendrá un comportamiento personalizado
- Controlar el movimiento del ratón
- Acceso a eventos de teclado
- ...

En Linux la cosa cambia debido a la filosofía reinante en este otro Sistema Operativo. Aquí tienes diferentes capas gráficas y será esta capa gráfica la que te va a proveer la funcionalidad básica para que tu puedas desplegar tu propia interfaz gráfica.

En el fondo, las librerías gráficas que puedes encontrar hoy no son más que utilidades que, haciendo uso de estas funciones que te digo, proporcionan un mecanismo más cómo de cara a crear entornos gráficos para las aplicaciones.

Comment: Ah, ¿Sería posible hacerlo sin la API del sistema operativo?

Comment: @ElblackNinja creo que he dejado bien claro que no... la api del SO estará siempre presente... otra cosa es que hables directamente con dicha api o o con una librería intermediaria

Comment: Mm ok, ya me quedo claro, gracias.